# Java JDBC query in separate thread lock parent

Tags: java, multithreading, oracle, jdbc

I'm having some trouble understanding this.
Here's what's happening.
I'm spawning a new thread that holds a JDBC connection to a Oracle database.
When I ask it to connect to the database, the parent thread keeps running while the start() method is invoked but when I ask the child to execute a query (on a separate method), the parent thread gets stuck waiting for the child thread's method to finish doing its work.
Any guess as how to fix this?
Thanks in advance!

```
public class Main extends Thread{

    public Main()
    {
    }

    public void myCounter() {
        int i = 0;
        DBConnection myConnection = null;
        for(;;)
        {
            i++;

            System.out.println("time: " + i);
            if( i  == 5)
            {
                myConnection = new DBConnection("localhost", 1521, "hr", "hr", "XE");
                myConnection.start();


            }
            if(i == 10)
                try {

                    myConnection.runQuery("Select * from hr.numbers order by dbms_random.value");
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void run()
    {
        myCounter();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Main boot = new Main();
        boot.start();

    }

}
```

---

```
public class DBConnection extends Thread{

    Connection myConnection;
    int port;
    String user;
    String password;
    String serviceName;
    String host;


    public void run()
    {
        setUpConnection(host, port, user, password, serviceName);
    }
    /**
     * Sets up variables to create a connection to Oracle.
     *  
     * @param host      host
     * @param port      port
     * @param user      user
     * @param password  password
     */
    public DBConnection(String host, int port, String user, String password, String serviceName)
    {
        this.host = host;
        this.port = port;
        this.user = user;
        this.password = password;
        this.serviceName = serviceName;
    }


    private void setUpConnection(String host, int port, String user,
            String password, String dataBase) {
        System.out.println("-------- Oracle "
                + "JDBC Connection Testing ------------");

        try {

            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

            System.out.println("Couldn't find Oracle JDBC Driver... :-(");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;

        }

        System.out.println("Oracle JDBC Driver Registered!");
        myConnection = null;
        try {
            myConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//" 
                            + host 
                            + ":" 
                            + port 
                            + "/" 
                            + dataBase,
                            user, password
                    );

        } catch (SQLException e) {

            System.out.println("Connection Failed!");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;

        }

        if (myConnection != null) {
            System.out.println("Connected to Oracle! :-)");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Failed to make connection!");
        }
    }


    /**
     * Queries the database and returns a ResultSet
     * @param  query            SQL
     * @throws SQLException 
     */
    public  ResultSet runQuery(String query) throws SQLException 
    {
        System.out.println("                                                    [DBConnection] Started Running @ " + (new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss:S")).format(new Date()));
        ResultSet rs = null;

        Statement stt = myConnection.createStatement();
        rs = stt.executeQuery(query);
        System.out.println("                                                    [DBConnection] Finished Running @: " + (new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss:S")).format(new Date()));
        return  rs;

    }
```

---

Here's the output I get:

```
time: 1
time: 2
time: 3
time: 4
time: 5
-------- Oracle JDBC Connection Testing ------------
Oracle JDBC Driver Registered!
time: 6
Connected to Oracle! :-)
time: 7
time: 8
time: 9
time: 10
                                                    [DBConnection] Started Running @ 14:46:00:660
                                                    [DBConnection] Finished Running @: 14:46:12:750
time: 11
time: 12
time: 13
time: 14
```

...
...
..
.

Comment: By the way, I created the table hr.numbers with 1.000.000+ records on purpose so it takes that long to finish.

Comment: You are calling the method runQuery on main Thread. The  sintaxe really doesn't help at all, but the fact that your myConnection is a new thread doesn't make your call to runQuery to execute in a new Thread. You have to keep checking a flag in your run method for start a query (on myConnection) and simple mark it on parent. Something like if (flag) { runQuery();}else{spleep(1000)}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you have misunderstood a bit how threads work. The problem is that you are calling this on the parent thread:

```
myConnection.runQuery("Select * from hr.numbers order by dbms_random.value");
```

which is a sequential invocation of the `runQuery` method on the `myConnection` object **that happens to be a thread**. This does not mean that it will instruct the child to execute the method. Instead the parent will execute it itself and the child thread finishes as soon as its `run` method has returned.

If you want to have a separate thread that keeps receiving commands to execute queries you will have to implement a producer-consumer pattern, where the parent keeps queuing commands for the child to execute. To this end I recommend you look at [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html).

Comment: Yes, it makes perfect sense. What do you thing by doing the following: create another thread that just handles the requests made to the DBConnection objects? Like Main creates a DBHandler object. DBHandler, on the other hand, creates a DBConnection object that is effectively the class that queries the database. So Main will ask stuff to DBHandler, which is the one that keeps waiting for DBConnection to return results. What do you think?

Comment: Of course I'll look at ExecutorService. If there's something that simplifies my work, I'll bem more than happy to use it. But still I'd like to figure out if there's some kind of workaround for this :-)

Comment: @user885878: Yes that would work. You just need to figure out how to pass the queries to the child thread for execution. A simple way is to use `Executor.newSingleThreadExecutor()`. This will effectively create a child thread that keeps polling a queue of tasks (all behind the scenes). In these tasks you can put queries that the child will automatically execute as they arrive.

Comment: Great! Thank you very very much for your help! I'll take a look in that right now! Have a nice day!

Comment: @user885878: You too. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

When you call `myConnection.runQuery()`, you are inside the `run()` method of the parent thread, so you are not in the `connection` thread even if you call one of its methods.

You should call `runQuery` inside the `run()` method of `myConnection` to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Your `runQuery` method is blocking since you call it on the main thread (So it will wait until the query is finished). If you want it to be called on another thread call it on the other's thread `run` method (just start the other thread where you would originally called for the query method)